# How to get webcam on webpage with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a webcam on my webpage,
it doesn't need to take a picture yet, but just the screen of what the webcam sees.
I can't get it working at the moment.

I used this website: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
I downloaded the plugin, but can't get the webcam on my page with jQuery.

What jQuery code do I need to use to get the image of the webcam on my page?
Someone maybe got an example of the code?

Answer (score 0):

As it says on the [website](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/), you can initialize the webcam plugin like this:

```
$("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function() {},
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
});
```